# Validate model after adding updating model

Tags: authentication, access-token, asp.net-core-webapi, model-validation

I am working on a web api on .net core. I am trying to validate/revalidate a model **after** adding additional data into the model (namely after adding the currently logged in user's username).

Let's say this is my controller's action

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public void Update([FromBody]UpdateUser User)
```

And here is the code I used for my authentication Scheme:

```
string token = Context.Request.Query["token"];
if (token == null) return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No JWT token provided");
try
{
    var principal = LoginControl.Validate(token);
    return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal, SchemeName));
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Failed to validate token");
}
```

Basically I am trying to achieve this flow: 
Post request -> Authorize-> add the user ID into the model -> validate the model.

So after authorized, I need to first add `User.UserName = CurrentUserName` and only the model needs to be validated, after which I can use the `ModelState` object on the newly updated model. 
As of now I am trying the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task Update([FromBody]UpdateUser User)
{
    User.UserName = "hello";
    bool valid = await TryUpdateModelAsync(User);
    valid = TryValidateModel(User);
}
```

Right now at both instances `valid` is false and the `ModelState` shows that `UserName` is required. The only validation I had added in UpdateUser is adding `[Required]` in the model.

Comment: i found the solution, but if anyone has ideas of making this functionality into a filter do let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by clearing the model before calling `TryValidateModel`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task Update(UpdateUser User)
{
    User.UserName = "hello";
    ModelState.Clear();
    TryValidateModel(User);
    // ModelState is now reset
}
```